# How to get JSON from ArcGIS Rest Server

Tags: arcgis, geoserver

I'm trying to download JSON file from ArcGIS Rest Server but received blank entries 2 (instead of 37 lacs).

```py
import requests

def download_restricted_data(url, username, password, output_path):
    session = requests.Session()
    session.auth = (username, password)
    try:
        response = session.get(url, stream=True)
        response.raise_for_status()

        with open(output_path, 'w') as file:
            file.write(response.text)

        print('Download complete.')
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print('Error occurred:', e)

base_url = 'https://mahabhumi.mrsac.org.in/server/rest/services/asset_mapping'
endpoint = '/Community_Well_Reference/MapServer/0/query?where=(np.where(pd.isnull(df))'
download_url = base_url + endpoint
```

I tried to change value .Null()